# Filter multiple numeric columns basis another numeric vector using R

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe with 2 numeric columns (with repetition of numbers). I need to filter both the columns using the values in another numeric vector and create a new dataframe with matching entries in both columns.

Eg. Dataframe `df` has two columns A and B:

```
A . B
1 . 2
1 . 3
5 . 7
8 . 7
7 . 1
```

Then, I have a vector `ind=c(1,2,5,7)`

Desired output will be a new dataframe with only the following rows:

```
A . B
1 . 2
5 . 7
7 . 1
```

Note: Only keep those rows where values of both A and B matches the vector values.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df$A %in% ind & df$B %in% ind,]
```

This is a fairly basic subset - you only select those rows where both A and B are `%in%` your index vector `ind`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help as I'm getting the following error:
'Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors'

Comment: That's odd... Can you provide a dput or at least str of your dataframe and vector? If worked for me with your sample data.